# QGIS Plugin: Creating a Plugin based on two scripts: where one script is dependent on another

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3, qgis-modeler

I have recently exported a model to a python script that is actually dependant on another Python Script I have converted from a previous model. Because the First Script/model F1 gets repeated three times (for all three vector types) and writing it three times is a hassle so I had to separate my completed model into two. But because of that I have a bit of trouble to convert these two scripts combined into 1 plug-in. Every tutorial I found spoke so far that of only one model to one script to one plug-in. But never have I found something like of where I convert two scripts, where the second script is dependant on the first script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add 2 or more scripts (i.e. algorithms) you need to add the new module (i.e. *algorithm_name*_algorithm.py file) into your plugin directory and then reference it in the provider module (i.e. *plugin_name*_provider.py).

First you tell the provider module to access the new algorithm from a different module by entering a line such as this at the top of you script:

```
from .new_algorithm import NewAlgorithm
```

Here *.new_algorithm* would be the same as the file name (i.e. new_algorithm.py) and *NewAlgorithm* would be the name of the class inside that file.

Next go down to the loadAlgorithms function (i.e. def loadAlgorithms(self)) and add the line:

```
self.addAlgorithm(NewAlgorithm())
```

That's it. As long as all the names match up between the 2 files you should now have 2 algorithms in your plug-in.

**An alternative, If you want to do as little coding as possible** is to add the models directly to your plugin without converting them to scripts.

First copy all the model files (*.model3) to your plug-in directory.

Second open the provider module (plugin_name_provider.py) and add the following 2 lines to the top:

```
import os
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingModelAlgorithm
```

Lastly, go down to you loadAlgorithms function and add the following lines:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(os.path.dirname(__file__)):
    for file_name in files:
        if file_name.lower().endswith('.model3'):
            alg = QgsProcessingModelAlgorithm()
            alg.fromFile(os.path.join(dirpath, file_name))
            self.addAlgorithm(alg)
```

This bit of code will cycle through your plug-in directory and any subdirectories and add all models that you have placed in there to your plug-in.